Do we ever remove the neutral connecting tab in a duplex receptacle?
I was wondering if there was ever a time when we would remove the silver tab/connector on a receptacle. I know that we remove bronze colored tab/connector when we have things like light switches that control one of the outlets, which I have done, but I left all of the silver tabs on.
My spouse decided to change most of the receptacles in our house without really knowing what she was doing and I'm just trying to fix it until an electrician can come.
I saw 4 different ways that the receptacles were wired.

The first was one black wire, one white wire and the ground.
The next was two black wires, two white wires and the ground.
The third was one black wire, one red wire (controlled by a light switch), two white wires and the ground.
The last way was one black wire, one red wire (controlled by a light switch), one white wire, and the ground.

I didn't remove any tabs/connectors for the first two cases.  The second two cases with the red wires, I only removed the bronze tab/connector.

@crip659 I'm not an electrician or even very good with electricity so I apologize if I use the wrong terminology or might be slow to catch on.  I don't think they are on separate circuits, when I shut the breaker for that receptacle, I think they both go out.  I'll double check to make sure as the light switch was always off and I never checked. with it on specifically.

Are your wires in cables or are they individual wires in conduit?

@manassehkatz, The wires are in cables (one cable with the black, white, red, and ground).

If your receptacle is served by two separate circuits, each with their own line and their own neutral, you would remove both the hot-side and the neutral-side tabs. Neutrals from separate cable runs can only be tied together at one point, either in the panel or the junction box where the cable originates.

It's somewhat rare to see this where I'm from, since you can save copper by running a multi-wire branch circuit instead.

Regarding what you have discovered in your walls:

one black wire, one white wire and the ground.

This is the simplest setup; you have one cable entering the box, powering the receptacle. No need to remove any tabs.



two black wires, two white wires and the ground.

Your receptacle is in the middle of a run of several devices. One of those cables runs "upstream" toward the breaker panel, the other runs "downstream" towards other receptacles or switches. If you were to disconnect all the wires and then turn on the breaker, you'll find some downstream devices on that circuit are not receiving power. Removing the tabs will cause downstream devices to fail: the power to downstream receptacles is actually being provided through the tabs.



one black wire, one red wire (controlled by a light switch), two white wires and the ground.

Per your comment, there is also a second black wire entering the box, and all black wires are joined with a wire nut. Likely this is a receptacle controlled by a switch, but this box also supplies unswitched power to a downstream device.  You must remove the hot tab for the switch to work.



one black wire, one red wire (controlled by a light switch), one white wire, and the ground.

Typical switched-receptacle layout. The red and black are on the same circuit, which goes through the switch box and then to the receptacle box. Inside the associated switch box you'll find a wire nut connecting two whites together. This also requires the hot tab to be removed.


Finally, a circuit that you didn't see (or may have seen and not understood): the multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC). This appears to have a red and a black wire into the hot side of your receptacle, with the tab broken, and a single neutral. But instead of being controlled by a switch, the red and the black are actually connected to the two different phases of your split-phase supply. One receptacle is on one phase, the other is on the other phase, and with a multimeter you can actually measure 240 VAC between them. In this setup, only the difference in current between each leg has to return through the white wire, and if the load on each leg is balanced, no current travels through the white wire at all.
Back at the breaker panel, you will should find MWBCs controlled by two breakers tied together with a handle (for safety, you must turn both off at the same time).

For an MWBC, the hot tab must be removed.
N.B.: all grounding connections have been left off the images; each device, box, and cable must have its grounding terminals/conductors connected together.

Old MWBC did not always have handle ties or have the breakers close enough.  Can make life interesting.

@Matt S,  with regards to your question "Are you sure there isn't another black wire somewhere in the box?", there is a nut and a some wires, I think it's a pigtail.  I also closed the breaker and checked the light switch and everything seems to be on the same circuit so that's good.

I've only skimmed the answer, but I have to say I love the drawings.

One more possibility that has not (I think) already been described:
MWBC using a regular double-breaker and splitting to two GFCI strings

Double-breaker (or, technically, two handle-tied single-breakers on different legs, but double-breaker is easiest)
Black/Red/White to a box in the kitchen with two GFCI/duplex receptacles
White splits to line neutral connection of both GFCI/receptacles (use a pigtail)
Red goes to line hot side of one GFCI/receptacle
Black goes to line hot side of one GFCI/receptacle
Two Black/White cables leave the box together, one from the load side of each GFCI/receptacle

The cables can go their own separate ways and be used with standard duplex receptacles around the kitchen. However, you have another option: top/bottom MWBC. In which case, in each box:

Two incoming Black/White cables
One cable goes to the top screws on the duplex receptacle
The other cable goes to the bottom screws on the duplex receptacle
BOTH TABS ARE REMOVED

If there are additional receptacles, use another two cables and either use better quality receptacles that have screw-to-clamp allowing two wires with each screw/clamp or use pigtails.
